# Using react-hook-form values as props using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup, react-hook-form

I am new to Typescript and having troubles getting the types to work correctly when I have `react-hook-form` values as props.

For example, I have a generic `Form` component that I use for many forms.

```js
interface Props {
  reactHookForm: UseFormMethods<any>
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any> 
  isDisabled?: boolean
  isLoading?: boolean
  isReadOnly?: boolean
  children: ReactElement
}

const Form = ({ reactHookForm, onSubmit, isDisabled = false, isLoading = false, isReadOnly = false, children }: Props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors, control, watch } = reactHookForm
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ register, errors, control, watch, isDisabled, isLoading, isReadOnly }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full">
        {children}
      </form>
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

And in an example component I have:

```js
const Auth = ({ onSignIn }: Props) => {
  const signInForm = useForm({ defaultValues, resolver })

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormData> = (values: FormData) => {
    const { email, password } = values

    const isAuthorized = (user: MyCustomUser) => {
      // do stuff
    }

    const onCompleted = () => {
      // do stuff
    }
    
    const onError = (error: MyCustomError) => {
      // do stuff
    }
    signInWithEmailAndPassword({ email, password, onCompleted, onError, isAuthorized })
  }

  return (
    <section className="flex h-full w-full justify-center items-center bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800">
        {/* some components... */}
        <Form reactHookForm={signInForm} onSubmit={onSubmit} isLoading={attemptingSignIn}>
          {/* form components */}
        </Form>
        {/* some more components ... */}
    </section>
  )
}
```

and with my `FormData`, `defaultValues` and `resolver` coming from file that looks something like:

```
import { Resolver } from "react-hook-form"
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup"
import { object, SchemaOf, string } from "yup"
import { createInputRequiredError } from "Components/Form/utils"

type FormData = {
  email: string
  password: string
}

const defaultValues: FormData = { email: "", password: "" }

const schema: SchemaOf<FormData> = object().shape({
  email: string().required(createInputRequiredError("email")),
  password: string().required(createInputRequiredError("password"))
})
const resolver = yupResolver(schema)

export type { FormData }
export { defaultValues, resolver }
```

My problem is that I have to use `reactHookForm: UseFormMethods<any>` and `onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any>` with the `any` type. React hook form has a `FieldValues` and I thought I could use this by having those types as  `reactHookForm: UseFormMethods` and `onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues>` however I get the following error:

```
Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ email: string; password: string; }': email, password
```

How can I set up the `reactHookForm` and `onSubmit` types so that they can be generic to any valid `react-hook-form` values?

---

**Update**

After upgrading my package to the latest version of `react-hook-form:7.3.0` I now have a slightly different message (I think these are still equivalent problems).

```
Type 'UseFormReturn<FormData>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormReturn<FieldValues>'.
  Types of property 'setError' are incompatible.
    Type 'UseFormSetError<FormData>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormSetError<FieldValues>'.
```

My Form provider was slightly update, it now looks like:

```js
interface Props {
  reactHookForm: UseFormReturn<any>
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any>
  isDisabled?: boolean
  isLoading?: boolean
  isReadOnly?: boolean
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[] | string
}

const Form = ({ reactHookForm, onSubmit, isDisabled = false, isLoading = false, isReadOnly = false, children }: Props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
    watch,
    getValues,
    setValue
  } = reactHookForm

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ register, errors, control, watch, getValues, setValue, isDisabled, isLoading, isReadOnly }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full">
        {children}
      </form>
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: any update on this, did you solve it ?

Comment: I no longer use this library sorry.

Comment: which library are you using then?

Comment: I am using Remix. Their framework is so great that I don’t need to use a client side form library.